Direct Limit of Coherent Rings with Flat Transition Maps is Coherent
Let $(A_{\alpha},\varphi_{\beta\alpha})$ be a direct system of right coherent rings such that for $\beta \geq \alpha$, $A_{\beta}$ is right flat over $A_{\alpha}$. Prove that the direct limit $A$ of this system is right coherent.
This is exercise 1.2.12.$e)$ in Commutative Algebra by Bourbaki. There are two hints:
Observe that $A$ is flat over all $A_{\alpha}$ and observe that for all finitely generated right ideals $I \subseteq A$, there exists an indice $\alpha$ and a finitely generated submodule $E_{\alpha} \subseteq A_{\alpha}$ such that $E_{\alpha} \otimes_{A_{\alpha}} A \cong I$.
Well, I cannot observe anything..
